# Magento configurable product price - using super products

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to configure Magento to use this prices for configurable product:

```
Configurable product "T-shirt"
Simple products:

"T-shirt" - color: blue; size: s; price: 1200
"T-shirt" - color: blue; size: m; price: 1300
"T-shirt" - color: blue; size: l; price: 1300

"T-shirt" - color: red; size: s; price: 1300
"T-shirt" - color: red; size: m; price: 1300
"T-shirt" - color: red; size: l; price: 1300
```

How to setup this in Magento store? I was trying to set -100 to color blue, but then all products that have blue color are -100.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this free extension: [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html). It allows you to set price of simple products in its properties, not in configurable product. Which I think simplifies everything.

Comment: thanks, I thought there can be "no extension" method. but will accept this as an answer

Comment: @boban0987 I see. Usually I'd also prefer 'no extension' solution. But in this particular case, this extension allowed my clients to use `price` column while CSV import. In regular way they'd have to do math for each ~2k products and fill it in `super_attribute_pricing` column using special formatting requirements - on each import. And that was not acceptable.

Comment: yes I understand. But how should I setup super attribute pricing for my case? Is there a way to set it up like that? Or it can just be set like this: all blue -100

Comment: @boban0987 have you tried this: [Tutorial: Creating a Configurable Product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product)?

Comment: yes I did, but as wrote in my example. you can set only all "blue" shirts to be -100. but if I need "blue" with size "s", then it is impossible to set using “Associated Products” tab